# Unable to import plotly in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

Getting this in the notebook(on antergos):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-6361d2547ebc> in <module>()
----> 1 import plotly

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'
```

When trying from the virtualenv's python interpreter with same sys.path and sys.executable

```
values, it imports fine like this:

python
import plotly
```

I am not using anaconda, but I am using virtualenv, set up following this guide: https://anbasile.github.io/programming/2017/06/25/jupyter-venv/ Checking the executable by running "which jupyter" points to the one local to the virtualenv. Pip freeze seems to output same thing in both cases:

```
backcall==0.1.0
certifi==2018.4.16
chardet==3.0.4
decorator==4.3.0
GDAL==2.3.1
idna==2.7
ipykernel==4.8.2
ipython==6.4.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
jedi==0.12.1
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter-client==5.2.3
jupyter-core==4.4.0
nbformat==4.4.0
parso==0.3.1
pexpect==4.6.0
pickleshare==0.7.4
plotly==3.0.0
prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
ptyprocess==0.6.0
Pygments==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.7.3
pytz==2018.5
pyzmq==17.1.0
requests==2.19.1
retrying==1.3.3
simplegeneric==0.8.1
six==1.11.0
tornado==5.1
traitlets==4.3.2
urllib3==1.23
wcwidth==0.1.7
```

Restarting the kernel doesn't seem to help either.